# Concatenate three different attributes to an array in Rust

Tags: rust

I have three attributes `a = 1`; `b = [0u8; 32]` and `c = 5`. I want to write a program in Rust which will accept these three inputs and concatenate them into one single array of type u8. So the resultant array looks like `[1, 0, ...... ,0, 5]`.

Is it possible to do this in Rust?

Comment: Does it have to be an array or does a `Vec<u8>` suffice?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible:

```rust
fn concat(a: u8, b: [u8; 32], c: u8) -> [u8; 34] {
    let mut res = [0; 34];
    res[0] = a;
    res[1..33].copy_from_slice(&b);
    res[33] = c;
    res
}
```